# Why do I have to store this Javascript object in a variable before pushing it to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm generating a tree in Javascript using this recursive function, which works:

```
function generate(depth){
        console.log('call '+depth);
        created_children = [];
        if (depth < 3) {
          for (i=0; i<3; i++){
            new_child = generate(depth+1);
            created_children.push(new_child);
          }
          console.log(created_children);
          return {text: 'lorem', children: created_children};
        }
        else
          return {text: 'lorem'};
      }
```

However, when I append my child nodes to `created_children` like this instead, `created_children` is empty.

```
 function generate(depth){
        console.log('call '+depth);
        created_children = [];
        if (depth < 3) {
          for (i=0; i<3; i++){

            created_children.push(generate(depth+1));
          }
          console.log(created_children);
          return {text: 'lorem', children: created_children};
        }
        else
          return {text: 'lorem'};
      }
```

Why does Javascript behave like this? Does a variable have to be named in local scope before it can be pushed on to an array? Does it have something to do with lazy evaluation?

Thanks,
Louise

Comment: One reason could be that `pus()` is a syntax error (missing h), but I'm hoping that's just a copy-paste-typo or something :)

Comment: The code is identical, assuming you mean `.push` and not `.pus`.  The issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: I guess `created_children.pus(generate(depth+1));` should be `created_children.push(generate(depth+1));`. Missing `h` in `push`

Comment: All your variables are global. Not quite sure what the function is supposed to do, but I can't see how even the first version could work.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think the problem is that, because the code seems to work perfectly. `new_child = generate(depth+1);created_children.push(new_child);` it's equal to `created_children.pus(generate(depth+1))`,the only difference is the typo mistake

Comment: Use local [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)iables!

Comment: Looks fine with local variables: https://repl.it/Bl3H

Comment: Typo fixed, it was introduced in the posting process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use global variables in recursion (or anywhere really, but this is just my opinion), it is a bad practice. The code below works just fine:

```
function generate(depth){
        if (depth < 3) {
          var created_children = [];
          for (i=0; i<3; i++){
            created_children.push(generate(depth+1));
          }
          return {text: 'lorem', children: created_children};
        }
        else
          return {text: 'lorem'};
      }

var tree = generate(0);
console.log(JSON.stringify(tree));
```

You can check it [here](https://repl.it/Bl3H/1)